# mocking a class is not working as expected

Tags: mockito, silhouette

In a function,  I am creating an instance of `CredentialsProvider` and calling its `authenticate` method.

```
val credentialsProvider = new CredentialsProvider(authInfoRepository, passwordHasherRegistory)
              val loginInfoFuture: Future[LoginInfo] = credentialsProvider.authenticate(credentials)
```

In my unit test, I am creating a mock of `CredentialsProvider`.

```
val mockCredentialsProvider = mock(classOf[CredentialsProvider])
```

and in my test case, I am mocking a value when `authenticate` is called.

```
when(testEnv.mockCredentialsProvider.authenticate(ArgumentMatchers.any[Credentials])).thenReturn(
        Future{
          println(s"mocked credentials provider will return ${testEnv.loginInfo}")
          testEnv.loginInfo}
      )
```

When I run my test case, it crashes. Looking at the stack trace, it seems that the actual implementation of `authenticate` gets called instead of simply returning a value.

```
at com.mohiva.play.silhouette.persistence.repositories.DelegableAuthInfoRepository.find(DelegableAuthInfoRepository.scala:51)
    at com.mohiva.play.silhouette.impl.providers.PasswordProvider.authenticate(PasswordProvider.scala:73)
    at com.mohiva.play.silhouette.impl.providers.PasswordProvider.authenticate$(PasswordProvider.scala:72)
    at com.mohiva.play.silhouette.impl.providers.CredentialsProvider.authenticate(CredentialsProvider.scala:46)
    at com.mohiva.play.silhouette.impl.providers.CredentialsProvider.$anonfun$authenticate$1(CredentialsProvider.scala:66)
```

Why my mocked code isn't working?

Comment: Because as you said, your function creates a new instance of CredentialsProvider, and thus doesn't use the other mock instance that you create in your test.

Comment: my misunderstanding then. I need to read more about Mockito then. I thought that every instance of `CredentialsProvider` will be mocked.

Comment: I could solve the issue by injecting `CredentialsProvider` in my method. Could you please tell me how I could test the original version if I didn't want to refactor the code?

Comment: You would need to use a more invasive (and slower) mocking framework such as PowerMock, which, AFAIK, can "mock" constructors. But yes, dependency injection is the key of testable code.

Comment: happy to accept your answer if you can provide one